# How to fix Mist node sync problems?

Tags: mist, nodes, synchronization, windows

I am having problems syncing Mist. I have tried versions 0.3.9 and 0.4.0.

I have been syncing for 4 days and I'm still stuck at 750.000 blocks of 1.000.000 blocks. I'm using Windows 10 64bit. Any ideas?